# How to modify subsequent points in an array

Tags: java, arrays

So for this pset I'm doing (for a Candy Crush clone), I have to write a method that checks for any possible matches in the row of a board that the chosen point is on. The method found would check to the right of the chosen point, and return an array of matching points to the chosen point. Within the given code, the `getRowBools` function is supposed to generate a boolean array with `true` or `false` depending on whether the points are the same as the chosen one. Then, the method would find the length of `true`s after the chosen one, then this length should determine the length of a new point array. Following that, the method is supposed to place all of the relevant points to the new array. However, I don't quite understand how to modify the point values in a way that works.

```
public static Point[] buildPossibleMatchRow(Point p, Board b) {

    int x = p.x;
    int y = p.y;
    boolean[] matches = b.getRowBools(new Point(x,y));

    int amtcorrectx = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < matches.length; i++)
    {
        if (matches[i]) {
            amtcorrectx++;
        }
    }
    Point[] returnVals = new Point[amtcorrectx];

    returnVals[0] = p;

    for (int i=0; i < returnVals.length; i++)
    {
        x++;
    }

    return returnVals;
}
```

Here's the code I have so far, but I'm sure that there's something wrong with the `for` loop at the end. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: The last `for` loops is just equivalent to `x + returnVals.length`... what are you trying to accomplish with that part of the code?

Comment: @mc10 : I think that's where he's supposed to place all of the relevant points to the new array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question, but looking at your code maybe you meant to accomplish something like this?

```
public static Point[] buildPossibleMatchRow(Point p, Board b) {
    int x = p.x;
    int y = p.y;
    boolean[] matches = b.getRowBools(new Point(x,y));

    int amountCorrect = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        if (matches[i])
            amountCorrect++;
    }

    Point[] result = new Point[amountCorrect];

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        result[i] = new Point(x + i, y);

    return returnVals;
}
```